# Facebook "pre-filling" policy unclear with regards to empty message and the link parameter

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, publish-actions

I'm trying to get publish_actions permissions approved for an iPhone app and been denied twice. The first time was because, as the policy says not to, we were populating the message parameter automatically when posting to the user's wall using the graph api. So we removed the message field entirely and kept only the link parameter.

The app was rejected again with the same message so I figured I'd try to get a definitive answer here before I get three strikes on app submission.

Both the 2.3 platform policy video and written policy explicitly say do not pre-fill the **message parameter** but say nothing about the **link** parameter. Beyond simply not pre-filling any of the message parameter must we also provide a way for the user to enter a message? If so that is not clear in the policy.

Graph Api Publish Documentation:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/feed#publish

"Pre-fill" Video: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill

Comment: The link parameter you can set. But the message parameter the user need to manually type every single character

Comment: Thanks for the comment @WizKid, would you happen to know if we have to provide the user the means to enter a message? Right now we just send an empty message.

Comment: Did you get approved in the end? I am having issues here too, and I have exactly the same set up as their video.

Comment: @MagicLAMP I'm afraid not, I was put on another project and I'm not sure if I'll get back to it.

Comment: does that mean the apps like postplanner.com are illigal - because it lets u post the trending content, which is not generated by user, also the content is reposted without original authors permission.

Answer (score 0):

I was rejected three times with the same response - which was you can not pre-populate the message field. But with the second and third submission, I was not pre-populating the message field. Of course I was expecting the Facebook reviewer to operate the application according to my instructions to see this. They don't, and the refusal was because they could not tell from my submission that this was the case. The response they give is not hand typed, but a stamped response given when they click "REFUSE!".

The solution is not only to get the application to behave according to policy, but to provide clear pictures with the step by step instructions of how your application shows the user the post, allows for the user to input a message, and the finished post on his time line.

Comment: It's a good idea to record a screencast and include that in the submission process along with the instructions in text.